# бесконечный слайдер

Tags: html, css

Слайдер работает,  НО, он не бесконечный а нужен именно такой, а также свойство rotate применяется только к 1 фото, их например 8, что нужно добавить чтобы все было безупречно?

```css
.gal {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate 15s linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.gal span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * 45deg)) translateZ(380px);
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * 45deg)) translateZ(380px);
}

.gal span img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="gal">
  <span style="--i:1">
    <img src="img/intro_bg.jpg" alt="intro">
    <img src="img/intro_bg.jpg" alt="intro">
    <img src="img/intro_bg.jpg" alt="intro">
    <img src="img/intro_bg.jpg" alt="intro">
    <img src="img/intro_bg.jpg" alt="intro">
    <img src="img/intro_bg.jpg" alt="intro">
    <img src="img/intro_bg.jpg" alt="intro">
    <img src="img/intro_bg.jpg" alt="intro">
  </span>
</section
```

Answer (score 0):

[`animation-iteration-count: infinite;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) или `animation: rotate 15s linear infinite;`

```css
.gal {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.gal span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * 45deg)) translateZ(380px);
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * 45deg)) translateZ(380px);
}

.gal span img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="gal">
  <span style="--i:1">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9rTKRxl.png" alt="intro">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9rTKRxl.png" alt="intro">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9rTKRxl.png" alt="intro">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9rTKRxl.png" alt="intro">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9rTKRxl.png" alt="intro">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9rTKRxl.png" alt="intro">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9rTKRxl.png" alt="intro">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9rTKRxl.png" alt="intro">
  </span>
</section
```